# Javascript onclick event not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, onclick

I have a button in our app that, when you click it, brings up a pop-up window asking if you are sure you want to proceed. Normally, that code would be in our HTML, but for this particular popup, it must be in Javascript. Anyway, the pop-up works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9, but it does NOT work in IE8. It is extremely frustrating. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Here is my code:

```
function graphicalAppConfirm() { 
var graphical = $('#application_graphical').is(':checked');
  if (graphical == true) {
    $('.default_action').attr('onclick', "return confirm('This setting cannot be undone. Are you sure you wish to continue?')"); 
}
  else {
   $('.default_action').removeAttr('onclick'); 
  }
}
```

I tried using the onmousedown event instead, and that made the popup appear, but then it would not go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using bind and unbind click. You don't necessarily care about the attributes.

```
function graphicalAppConfirm() { 
var graphical = $('#application_graphical').is(':checked');
  if (graphical == true) {
    $('.default_action').click(function() { return confirm('This setting cannot be undone. Are you sure you wish to continue?'); }); 
} else {
   $('.default_action').unbind('click'); 
  }
}
```

If you're using jQuery 1.7+ then on/off is recommended instead of bind/unbind. See the documentation http://api.jquery.com/off/

Update: Here is an example with jQuery 1.8 which you can modify for your own usage. You'll probably want to perform the on/off functions when the checkbox is changed so that is how this example works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="theone">Does nothing...</button>
  <label for="check"><input id="check" type="checkbox" />Enable Button</label>
  <div id="output" style="display:none;">Click registered.</div>

  <script>
    function callback() {
      $("#output").show().fadeOut("slow");
    }

    $("#check").change(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("body").on("click", "#theone", callback)
          .find("#theone").text("Click Me Enabled!");
      } else {
        $("body").off("click", "#theone", callback)
          .find("#theone").text("Click Me Disabled");
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can figure out the rest from there. You can test and see it work in IE 8 http://jsbin.com/ojejar/6

Comment: I am using JQuery 1.8 so that should not be an issue. Alas, your suggestion did not work. It didn't break anything either, but unfortunately, the IE8 problem remains.

Comment: I agree with this answer - you shouldn't be using the attr method to set a click event. If .click and .unbind didn't work, it is likely a problem with the code inside the confirm method, which I imagine displays the pop up?

Comment: Yes, the only code inside the confirm method is displaying a popup window with a message within it. I can't imagine there's anything wrong with that code and, like I said, my code works in EVERY browser with the sole exception of IE 8 (it works just great in IE 9). Also, I have to admit, I'm primarily a Javascript coder, and a newbie at that, so I am having problems translating the JQuery code above to Javascript. Could anyone help me out with that?

Comment: Ahhhhh, I apologize. Got up on the wrong side of the bed today, I guess. I was looking at our JQuery-UI... we have version 1.8.6 of JQuery-UI, but only version 1.6.1 of JQuery. My mistake. The .on() and .off() methods were added in 1.7, so no wonder I couldn't get this to work. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: My suggestion is try making it work in the simplest form like I did above. Then make it work with your code base. There is clearly something wrong with your code as the examples I posted work in IE 8.

Comment: After spending some time debugging my code, it appears that the code in the conditional is never executed in IE8 (yet it is in every other browser... odd). So maybe this line:
    var graphical = $('#application_graphical').is(':checked');
is at fault, though I don't know why. I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: Try `var graphical = document.getElementById('#application_graphical').checked;`

Comment: Thanks, styfle. I got permission to upgrade our JQuery. After doing so, and being able to use the .on() and .off() functionality, that should fix my problem. Thanks so much!